# Object doesn't support property or method 'done'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using 'beforeSend' to call a function that will validate whether or not a select box option is greator than zero.  If so, it returns true, else it returns false.  So far, so good.

The problem I'm having is that when it return false, I'm seeing "Object doesn't support property or method 'done'" in the JavaScript debug screen.  Otherwise, all is well.

```
function validateForm()
{
    if($('#p_employee').val() == 0)
    {
        $('#errorMessage').text(' *** Please select an employee. ***');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;        
    }   
}

function populateEmployeeDiv()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type:           "post",
        url:            "populateEmployeeDiv.cfm",
        cache:          false,
        dataType:       "html",
        target:         'employeeDiv',
        data:           {
                            p_employee: $('#p_employee').val()
                        },
        beforeSend:     function() { 
                                        return validateForm();
                                   }
    })
    .done(function(content){

        $('#employeeDiv').html(content);

    })
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to clean up your code using the editor preview. [There's a help page for learning to use markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: did i miss something? the code looks relatively clean

Comment: "Returning `false` in the `beforeSend` function will cancel the request."  So, `$.ajax` is probably returning `null`, which doesn't have a `.done()` method.  Try to use `success:` in your `$.ajax` options instead.

Answer (score 2):

That's a strange place to validate the form? Why not just validate it first, and then do the ajax call if it's valid ?

```
function populateEmployeeDiv() {

    if ( validateForm() ) {
        $.ajax({
            type     : "post",
            url      : "populateEmployeeDiv.cfm",
            cache    : false,
            dataType : "html",
            target   : 'employeeDiv',
            data     : { p_employee: $('#p_employee').val() }
        }).done(function(content){
            $('#employeeDiv').html(content);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Validating the requirements before the AJAX call is usually how I do it.  It seems like beforeSend helps clean up or streamline the code some.

Comment: Success did it.  Thank You!